# Sorting AWS AppSync 'GraphQL' connected queries (nesting sorting?)

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I am Using AWS AppSync for my react native application and can't seem to figure out how to get sort inside of a query (nested queries/sorting?). Not sure what the proper terminology would be but here are my `graphQL` models, each month can contain many `monthsPhotos`:

```
type Month
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [read, create, delete, update] }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  owner: String!
  monthsphotos: [MonthPhoto] @hasMany
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
  sorttype: String!
    @index(
      name: "monthsByDateTime"
      queryField: "monthsByDateTime"
      sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"]
    )
}

type MonthPhoto
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [read, create, delete, update] }]) {
  id: ID!
  month: Month @belongsTo
  thumbnail: String
  owner: String!
  caption: String
  location: String
  date: String
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
  monthMonthsphotosId: ID!
    @index(
      name: "monthPhotosByDateTime"
      queryField: "monthPhotosByDateTime"
      sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"]
    )
  file: S3Object
}
```

my query for my months looks like this:

```
export const monthsByDateTime = /* GraphQL */ `
  query MonthsByDateTime(
    $sorttype: String!
    $createdAt: ModelStringKeyConditionInput
    $sortDirection: ModelSortDirection
    $filter: ModelMonthFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    monthsByDateTime(
      sorttype: $sorttype
      createdAt: $createdAt
      sortDirection: $sortDirection
      filter: $filter
      limit: $limit
      nextToken: $nextToken
    ) {
      items {
        id
        name
        monthsphotos {
          items {
            file {
              bucket
              region
              key
            }
            createdAt
            caption
            date
            location
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

This lets me sort my months data by the date and time is was created. Ultimately I want a query that sorts all the months, and also sorts all the `monthsPhotos` within those months in 1 query. How would I go about doing this? Below is another query I made to sort `monthsPhotos` alone, I have not figured out how to connect these two into one:

```
export const monthPhotosByDateTime = /* GraphQL */ `
  query MonthPhotosByDateTime(
    $monthMonthsphotosId: ID!
    $createdAt: ModelStringKeyConditionInput
    $sortDirection: ModelSortDirection
    $filter: ModelMonthPhotoFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    monthPhotosByDateTime(
      monthMonthsphotosId: $monthMonthsphotosId
      createdAt: $createdAt
      sortDirection: $sortDirection
      filter: $filter
      limit: $limit
      nextToken: $nextToken
    ) {
      items {
        id
        file {
              bucket
              region
              key
            }
        caption
        location
        date
        createdAt
        monthMonthsphotosId
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```